# Can I use TSDuck's tsp tool for HLS with token-based authentication?

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, transport-stream

I have developed a TSDuck plugin which I use within the `tsp` tool to extract data from specific packets.  Up till now I've always used this directly on an SRT stream, but I now have a use case to apply the same process to an HLS stream with a bespoke token-based authentication.

In ffmpeg, I can access the video via:

```
ffmpeg -headers x-affiliate-auth-key:{token} -i https://{url}/index.m3u8
```

However, I do not see any equivalent option to `-headers` to use within `tsp`, so as you would expect this fails (because `tsp` will receive an HTTP error message, not an HLS manifest):

```
tsp -I hls https://{url}/index.m3u8 -O file /tmp/test.mp4
* Error: hls: invalid HLS playlist, does not start with #EXTM3U
```

Is there any way to pass custom headers through `tsp` for HLS input?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recent code contribution added options `--headers` to the TSDuck `hls` input plugin. Will be included in version 3.36 (about to be released) or recent nightly builds.

Comment: Hah, that contribution was from me (OP), after I got no response here.  I completely forgot I asked this here, or I would have answered my own question.